# boost::format vs sprintf

Tags: c++, boost

Which one is better: `boost::format` or `sprintf`?
I also want to know which one is more type safe to use.

I know one limitation with `sprintf` that it formats a `char[]` object, and the size of `char[]` should be sufficient to hold the formatted string. But does `boost::format` also hold the same limitation or not. can Anyone point out me a doc on net which I would refer for the difference among `boost::format` and `sprintf`.

Comment: I suggest having a look at [this article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm). It doesn't talk about boost::format specifically, but covers `sprintf` and compares to other methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In terms of robustness and type-safety boost::format is a clear winner. It doesn't have an issue with buffer size as it uses a dynamic stream. The types of the parameters are retained in the function call, thus the formatter can intelligently convert. This also means there is no problem of screwing up the stack with mismatched types. Type conversion is also available in this model.

The drawbacks of format are its speed and that it is a bit cumbersome. Its speed is quite a bit lower than that of sprintf for formats that sprintf can handle. Its syntax is also a bit more involved than a quick call to sprintf.

For simple token formatting I usually use sprintf. For complex string formatting I tend to use boost format, or iostreams.

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf()` is not type-safe; therefore `boost::format` will be more type-safe.  `sprintf()` is prone to buffer overflow; you'd be better off using `snprintf()` than `sprintf()`, but you're very likely to be better off still with `boost::format`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define "better".

`printf` is quite fast and readily available being a part of standard library. However it has safety issues that are to some extent addressed with [__attribute__ ((format (printf, ...))](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) in GCC.

Boost Format is safe, but it is [much slower](https://github.com/cppformat/cppformat#speed-tests) and, as pointed out by `@edA-qa mort-ora-y`, somewhat cumbersome to use due to unconventional use of `operator%`.

If you want the best of both world, the convenient function-call formatting API and speed of `printf`, and safety of Boost Format, consider the [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library. It supports both `printf` and Python's `str.format` syntax:

```
fmt::print("Hello, {}!", "world");  // uses Python-like format string syntax
fmt::printf("Hello, %s!", "world"); // uses printf format string syntax
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of {fmt}